# Advantage of Logs and DBs on separate SAS HDDs on dedicated server?

Tags: performance, logging, storage, database, sas

Is there any significant performance advantage of having log data (application + DB) and DB data on separate SAS drives (for a dedicated server running CentOS) because writes of logging and db will cause writes to be random while keeping things separate will allow more sequential writes (I might be wrong here!).

Also, logs are mostly write only, while I expect my DB to be 90/10 read/write.

Comment: It is not about how the relative number of reads and writes compare but about the absolute IOPS, nine reads per minute vs 1 write you could manage from an old floppy drive. ... 9000/1000 per second is something completely different. (IIRC a 15k SAS drive supports 200 IOPS)

Comment: Lets say we are talking about server at max capacity, because performance will be important in that situation!

Comment: `Lets say we are talking about server at max capacity` - That's a meaningless statement. What does max capacity mean in this case? How are you quantifying max capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major advantage of having separate disks, is the ability to recover data in the event of a failure.

If you take regular backups of the database, and record transaction logs to a different disk than the database, if either disk fails, you can quickly get up and running without any database data being lost (restore from the backup, and replay the transaction logs, to recreate the database at the time of the disk fail).

You are also correct about disk IO.  The more spindles you have working on parallel workloads the more performant you are.

You may however want to also consider utilising RAID.  I would much rather run a database in RAID 10, and be able to hot swap out a disk with zero downtime in the event of a failure, then split 4 disks as 2 databases and 2 logs, and have a database outage after a disk failure, even if I can recover all of the data.

RAID 10 can also give a significant boost in disk read speed, which might have a greater effect on database reads.

The best solution will differ based on the type of database you run, the number of disks available, the uptime requirements, performance requirements and other hardware restraints.

In an ideal world, you would be able to utilise all of the above techniques and do so on multiple database servers to form a redundant cluster.